# Base64 image shows in outlook email body but in Gmail it does not show the image, Gmail is not recognising the base64 string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, base64, email-templates

I have an email template which is in Azure, in asp.net core api iam generating QR in base64 string and i use that as that as img src (like this : <img src="{{QRstring}}") the value of {{QRstring}} is like "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR........................................VORK5CYII="
now this works perfectly for Outlook but in Gmail it does not display

what approach i can use where i can show QR to all Email clients without any issues?

this is how iam generating QR:

```
public async Task<string> QRGenerate(Model model)
        {
            QRCodeData qrCodeData;
            string qrData = $"abcd";

            using (QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator())
            {
                qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(qrData, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            }

            var imgType = Base64QRCode.ImageType.Png;
            var qrCode = new Base64QRCode(qrCodeData);
            string qrCodeImageAsBase64 = "data:image/png;base64," + qrCode.GetGraphic(20, SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.Black, SixLabors.ImageSharp.Color.White, true, imgType);

            return qrCodeImageAsBase64;
        }
```

whatever string value i get from qrCodeImageAsBase64 iam using it in that {{QRstring}}, again this works for Outlook but not Gmail

Comment: it's pretty common for e-mail clients to not support base64.  It shouldn't be used anyway, since the size will always be larger than just attaching the file.  The best thing to do is host the image remotely and then link it.  That makes the message size much smaller.